# Could not find class 'com.google.android,gms.maps.supportfragment

Tags: android, google-maps

I m working with google maps and have followed [this](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/306-urok-139-google-maps-sozdanie-i-nastrojka-proekta-karta-kamera-sobytija.html) tutorial.I have written my code below.I m getting the error in logcat that Could not find class 'com.google.android,gms.maps.supportfragment.Plz help me.thanks in advance.

```
package com.google.android.gms;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

  SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
  GoogleMap map;
  final String TAG = "myLogs";

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    map = mapFragment.getMap();
    if (map == null) {
      finish();
      return;
    }
    init();
  }

  private void init() {
    }


  public void onClickTest(View view) {
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
  }
}
```

Here is Logcat:

```
11-14 12:24:21.506: I/dalvikvm(1383): Could not find method com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.setMapType, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.MainActivity.onClickTest
11-14 12:24:21.536: W/dalvikvm(1383): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4792: Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap;.setMapType (I)V
11-14 12:24:21.536: D/dalvikvm(1383): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0003
11-14 12:24:21.567: E/dalvikvm(1383): Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.MainActivity.onCreate
11-14 12:24:21.576: W/dalvikvm(1383): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 683 (Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment;) in Lcom/google/android/gms/MainActivity;
11-14 12:24:21.576: D/dalvikvm(1383): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x0013
11-14 12:24:22.016: D/AndroidRuntime(1383): Shutting down VM
11-14 12:24:22.016: W/dalvikvm(1383): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414c4700)
11-14 12:24:22.046: E/AndroidRuntime(1383): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-14 12:24:22.046: E/AndroidRuntime(1383): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class fragment
11-14 12:24:22.046: E/AndroidRuntime(1383):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
11-14 12:24:22.046: E/AndroidRuntime(1383):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
11-14 12:24:22.046: E/AndroidRuntime(1383):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-14 12:24:22.046: E/AndroidRuntime(1383):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
11-14 12:24:22.046: E/AndroidRuntime(1383):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-14 12:24:22.046: E/AndroidRuntime(1383):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-14 12:24:22.046: E/AndroidRuntime(1383):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
11-14 12:24:22.046: E/AndroidRuntime(1383):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-14 12:24:22.046: E/AndroidRuntime(1383):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-14 12:24:22.046: E/AndroidRuntime(1383):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
11-14 12:24:22.046: E/AndroidRuntime(1383):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-14 12:24:22.046: E/AndroidRuntime(1383):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-14 12:24:22.046: E/AndroidRuntime(1383): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class fragment
11-14 12:24:22.046: E/AndroidRuntime(1383):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
11-14 12:24:22.046: E/AndroidRuntime(1383):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
11-14 12:24:22.046: E/AndroidRuntime(1383):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
11-14 12:24:22.046: E/AndroidRuntime(1383):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
11-14 12:24:22.046: E/AndroidRuntime(1383):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
11-14 12:24:22.046: E/AndroidRuntime(1383):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
11-14 12:24:22.046: E/AndroidRuntime(1383):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
11-14 12:24:22.046: E/AndroidRuntime(1383):     at com.google.android.gms.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
11-14 12:24:22.046: E/AndroidRuntime(1383):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
11-14 12:24:22.046: E/AndroidRuntime(1383):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-14 12:24:22.046: E/AndroidRuntime(1383):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
11-14 12:24:22.046: E/AndroidRuntime(1383):     ... 11 more
11-14 12:24:22.046: E/AndroidRuntime(1383): Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
11-14 12:24:22.046: E/AndroidRuntime(1383):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:409)
11-14 12:24:22.046: E/AndroidRuntime(1383):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:377)
11-14 12:24:22.046: E/AndroidRuntime(1383):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:277)
11-14 12:24:22.046: E/AndroidRuntime(1383):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
11-14 12:24:22.046: E/AndroidRuntime(1383):     ... 21 more
11-14 12:24:22.046: E/AndroidRuntime(1383): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.google.android.gms-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.google.android.gms-2, /system/lib]]
11-14 12:24:22.046: E/AndroidRuntime(1383):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
11-14 12:24:22.046: E/AndroidRuntime(1383):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
11-14 12:24:22.046: E/AndroidRuntime(1383):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
11-14 12:24:22.046: E/AndroidRuntime(1383):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:399)
11-14 12:24:22.046: E/AndroidRuntime(1383):     ... 24 more
```

This is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical">
<Button
 android:id="@+id/btnTest"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:onClick="onClickTest"
 android:text="test">
</Button>
<mapfragment
 android:id="@+id/map"
 android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">
</mapfragment>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Show your map xml please

Comment: I have added it in question.

Comment: ah hah i will edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

You also need the support library, not just the play services library.
Open the sdk manager and download it, then include it in your project.

Your mapfragment should look like this in xml:

```
<fragment
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer...But I have already installed android support library from SDK manager.

Comment: did you give it the id= and class=?
I'll edit my answer for something else you might need

Comment: actually i have not installed Google API.but in my SDK manager,there is no option for Google API.plz help me

Comment: Its not towards the very bottom with all the other libraries?